# TRIGGER SQL after delete, delete row on the second table... :S

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, triggers

I created a trigger for copy values from table1 to table2:

```
INSERT INTO table_2 (destinationid, destinationrow1, destinationrow2)
SELECT originid, originrow1, originrow2 FROM table_1
WHERE rowtype='special_value'
```

Well, I don't understand how to create the trigger so that when a specific id is deleted in the Table 1 also do it in Table 2.

Comment: Create a foreign key reference in table 2 that is based on the primary key in table 1 and define cascading delete.

Comment: foreign key are already mentioned, but since I don't understand your "copy trigger" you might investigate [Use the inserted and deleted Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/us-en/library/ms191300.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the help. 

When I generate the foreign key for tables works only when I insert one record. When inserting the second record in Table 1 the trigger back all the records and duplicate IDs so that I have a SQL error. 

Thanks for the link, I continue to search for solutions within. If anyone has an idea I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Well, I solved the problem by adding another trigger to clear the cells before inserting the new. Now this is useful but I understand that is not the right way.